# Android- HttpUrlConnection addRequestProperty not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

After doing more research I am now able to clarify my question. I have a code segment that I know works with every other file I try it on except one text file. The code checks the file I send it using the URL and HTTPURLConnection. I use `addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-0")` to get just enough of the file on the server so I can check the LastModified field without having to download the file again. Here is the code for the checking of the file:

```
  private void getFileDetails() throws IOException, ParseException {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-0");
    con.connect();
    String cr = con.getHeaderField("Content-Range");
    URL url2 = new URL("url for json file");
    URL url3 = new URL("url for txt file");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();
    if(url.equals(url2) || url.equals(url3)) {//This is just for seeing if it added Range
        Log.i("HTTP", url.toString());
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Log.i("HTTP", "Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                    " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
        Log.i("HTTP", "----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    if (cr == null)//Fails Right here
        throw new IOException();
    length = Long.parseLong(cr.substring(cr.indexOf('/')+1, cr.length()));
    String date = con.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
    String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date javaDate = format.parse(date);
    lastModified = javaDate.getTime();
}
```

Here is the output of my test on the fields for the file that worked:

```
  I/HTTP: Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content]
  I/HTTP: Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
  I/HTTP: Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
  I/HTTP: Key : Content-Length ,Value : [1]
  I/HTTP: Key : Content-Range ,Value : [bytes 0-0/15431]
  I/HTTP: Key : Content-Type ,Value : [application/json]
  I/HTTP: Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 11 Jan 2018 17:54:00 GMT]
  I/HTTP: Key : ETag ,Value : ["3c47-560c8525e5d0b"]
  I/HTTP: Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=100]
  I/HTTP: Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 20 Dec 2017 16:46:15 GMT]
  I/HTTP: Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)]
  I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Received-Millis ,Value : [1515693240969]
  I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Response-Source ,Value : [NETWORK 206]
  I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Selected-Protocol ,Value : [http/1.1]
  I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Sent-Millis ,Value : [1515693240804]
```

Now here is the result of the text file that doesn't work:

```
 I/HTTP: Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
 I/HTTP: Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
 I/HTTP: Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
 I/HTTP: Key : Content-Type ,Value : [text/plain]
 I/HTTP: Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 11 Jan 2018 17:55:44 GMT]
 I/HTTP: Key : ETag ,Value : ["1370000-560b66148adf5-gzip"]
 I/HTTP: Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=100]
 I/HTTP: Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Tue, 19 Dec 2017 19:21:56 GMT]
 I/HTTP: Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)]
 I/HTTP: Key : Transfer-Encoding ,Value : [chunked]
 I/HTTP: Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding]
 I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Received-Millis ,Value : [1515693344544]
 I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Response-Source ,Value : [NETWORK 200]
 I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Selected-Protocol ,Value : [http/1.1]
 I/HTTP: Key : X-Android-Sent-Millis ,Value : [1515693344397]
```

You can see that the Content-Range field is missing from the text files headers and the status message is OK instead of Partial Content. I know that because I'm getting the true for `cr == null` means that it doesn't exist in the header files for the text file. I don't understand what is going wrong with the add. Everywhere I've looked where people have had similar problems the whole thing doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Ok so the real problem is that the text file has no Length field. It checks the LastModified and the size of the file to see if it needs an update.

Edit: I know what's wrong now. The text file is chunked encoded and has no `Content-Length`

Comment: Are you using ETags for determining these resource changes?

Comment: Yes, in a way. I figured out what the problem was just recently discovered how to solve the problem I was having. I'll post the answer and explain more what had happened.

Answer (score 0):

After much work and research, I discovered that the file I was trying to check the Content-Length tag on was chunked encoded which takes that tag away. The Apache server the files are hosted on automatically chunks .txt files that are too large. A workaround to this problem was to simply change the file extension from .txt to a .bin file. Doing that gave me the Content-Length header allowing me to check the size of the file without having to actually download the file. Apparently, the automated chunked encoding is something that is standard in HTTP 1.1. I'm not sure if that's the best way to get around this issue, but it worked in my case. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this the wrong way. You should be using a HEAD request. That way nothng is sent in reply except the headers, so no chunk encoding, and no Range header is necessary either,

Comment: Can I get the size of the file via a HEAD request?

Comment: Of course. That's why I suggested it. Oddly enough.

Comment: This code was written before me getting to this project and I guess it worked for a while, but when I tried to check the .txt file it broke. I know my higher ups are going to change the .txt files to bins in the future anyway, but I will check out the HEAD request and see if I can change the existing code anyway. Thanks for the suggestion.